# Saving list to a .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, nested, export-to-csv

I have made a code that opens a .csv file and takes a user input to filter it to a new list. What I am having trouble with is saving this new list to a .csv file properly.

This is my code:

```
@author: Joakim

from pprint import pprint
import csv

with open ('Change_in_Unemployment_2008-2014.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

next(readCSV)     #Removing header 

result = []
found = False
user_input = input("Please enter a full/partial NUTS code to filter by: ")
for row in readCSV:
    if row[0].startswith(user_input):
        result.append(row)
        found = True
if found == False:
    print("There are no registered NUTS codes containing your input.. Please try again")
if found == True:
    print("\n Successfully found ", len(result), "entries!""\n")

pprint (result)

#store data in a new csv file

Stored_path = "C:\data_STORED.csv"
file = open(Stored_path, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["NUTS CODE", " Municipality", " value"])
for i in range(len(result)):
    new_row = result[i]
    NUTS_CODE = new_row[0]
    Municipality = new_row[1]
    Value = new_row[2]
    writer.writerow([NUTS_CODE, Municipality])






csvfile.close()
```

If one runs my code with an input of : PL, one gets this list:

```
[['PL11', 'odzkie', '2.2'],
['PL12', 'Mazowieckie', '1.2'],
['PL21', 'Maopolskie', '2.9'],
['PL22', 'Slaskie', '2'],
['PL31', 'Lubelskie', '1.1'],
['PL32', 'Podkarpackie', '5.8'],
['PL33', 'Swietokrzyskie', '2.6'],
['PL34', 'Podlaskie', '2.7'],
['PL41', 'Wielkopolskie', '1.6'],
['PL42', 'Zachodniopomorskie', '-1.1'],
['PL43', 'Lubuskie', '1.8'],
['PL51', 'Dolnoslaskie', '0'],
['PL52', 'Opolskie', '1.3'],
['PL61', 'Kujawsko-Pomorskie', '1.6'],
['PL62', 'Warminsko-Mazurskie', '2.4'],
['PL63', 'Pomorskie', '3.1']]'
```

Now I would like to store this neatly into a new .csv file, but when I use the code above, I only get a couple of values repeated throughout. 
What is my error?

Comment: What do you mean with *"I only get a couple of values repeated throughout. "*? I ran your code with the list you provided and it seems to work (mostly) correctly. To avoid the extra newlines, pass `newline=''` here `open(Stored_path, 'w', newline='')`. And you also forgot to write the values `writer.writerow([NUTS_CODE, Municipality, Value])`. BTW, please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Ive gotten it to work, but now they are all being saved as a long row of many smaller lists. I would like to have them in a row fashion inside the .csv. is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit the question. Update your code and the example input and output.